# Ubuntu 14.04 ethernet slow

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

Hey since this morning my Ubuntu 14.04 Ethernet connection is really slow but the strange thing is I have a hotspot in my machine and the phone connected to it has fast Internet..........

I really don´t remember that I changed something to my system I am confused as tux.

How do i fix this

my Ethernet details

```
description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 14:da:e9:ab:36:dc
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:58 memory:dc800000-dc83ffff ioport:9000(size=128)
```

Comment: so what is the question ?

Comment: first thing you have to do is to call your ISP to verify if there's any connection problem

Comment: post `ifconfig -a`, `ping -c10 8.8.8.8` and `wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip`